# Proving that $\log_2 7$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $\log_2 7$ is irrational.

Book solution: Suppose $\log_2 7$ is rational. Then $\log_2 7=a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. **We may assume that $a>0$ and $b>0$.** We have $2^{a/b}=7$, which implies $2^a=7^b$. But the number $2^a$ is even and the number $7^b$ is odd, a contradiction. Hence, $\log_2 7$ is irrational.

I understand this proof, but my question is whether or not the assumption that $a,b>0$ is really necessary. Is this a necessary condition for the proof to hold? It doesn't seem like it. For $\log_a b=c$, we know $c$ must be positive. Hence, $a/b$ must be positive, meaning $a,b>0$ or $a,b<0$. If $a$ and $b$ were both negative though, the "even and odd" argument at the end would no longer be valid but only semantically. That is, we would have $1/2^{|a|}$ and $1/7^{|b|}$, where you could still argue via parity that the denominators would be different but the numerators the same, hence not equivalent.

Did I miss something or was this assumption not all that necessary?

Comment: You are right. I think use positive number just to simplify the proof.

Comment: It isn't necessary.  But it is true, and they state that fact instead of cross multiplying in the end as you showed.  Eitherway you are going to have to state something additional: Either cross multiply in the end, or insist that a and b are both positive (which we know can always be done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption isn't necessary; they trade that step for the step saying $2^{|a|}=7^{|b|}$ by cross multiplying.

Also note that $\log_ab\geq0$ isn't always the case (your post makes it seems like $\log_ab=c$ implies $c>0$); however $\ln(1/e)=-1$, for example.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was sloppy in my phraseology--your last part addresses that and for this particular problem I think it's all clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we know that log2(7) is a positive number. So it can be represented as a/b for positive a,b if it is rational. Assuming this just makes it easier so that you have integers on both sides of the equality.

As to the proof: If 2^a = k^b, k has to be a power of 2, or else by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic k^b has primes in its factorization other than 2 and thus is not equal to 2^a. This could help you if you have other numbers instead of 2 and 7.

Comment: I don't really see how this addresses my problem at all. I know about the FTA but my question here is about the assumption concerning positivity or negativity of $a,b$.

Comment: a and b both being positive or negative does not change much as you've stated in the problem. So, the assumption is just to make the proof easier. I mentioned FTA, because it adresses the part about the validity of even-odd argument. Even-odd argument is weaker than FTA for a proof like this, and it's not that required if FTA is instead used. What would you do if you had 3^a=5^b ?

Comment: Using even-odd argument instead of FTA can also be seen as an indication that the proof was written to be as simple as possible.